# detecting change in a binary column vector

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

I am new to matlab, I have a column vector with binary values
I want to get the indices where the value changes from 0 to 1, and the indices when there is a change from 1 to 0.

This is my first question to Stackoverflow so am hoping to get the needed help,
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the `diff` function.

Comment: @Maurits, you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `diff` with `find`.

```
x = rand(1, 10) > 0.5

% all changes
find(diff(x)) + 1

% 0 to 1 and 0 to 1 separately
find(diff(x) == 1) + 1
find(diff(x) == -1) + 1
```

Comment: If the answer was useful, you can upvote by cliking the up arrow on the left.  (You can do this as well as marking an answer as accepted.)